# readline: Convert input to upper case on screen as it is typed

Tags: readline, uppercase

How can I instruct `readline` to convert keyboard intput to upper case, as it is typed, and have that be the echo to the terminal?

(Related, [python: Convert input to upper case on screen as it is typed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36611748/70157) — which asks a different question trying to achieve a similar result. This is not a Python-specific question, so is not a duplicate of that one.)

The program I'm writing (which is Python 3 code, if that matters) uses the `readline` library for command line input, so implementing conversion of each keystroke is not an option. I'm looking for a way to do this by requesting the `readline` library do it for me.

The existing commands `upcase-word` and `downcase-word` are for the user to invoke, to deliberately change the case of text already typed. That isn't what I need; instead I want the text to be changed immediately as it's typed in.

Answer (score 0):

You have only 3 options I guess:

1. Changing your Keyboard firmware in way that it sends a *CAPS-Lock on* signal in start-up!
2. Modifying your keyboard driver in the operation System to send the OS uppercase letters instead of the lower-cases.
3. Modifying source code of the Shell that you see the result of your Typing inside, in a way that it show upper-cases always.

You can't aim this goal using the program is running!